# django import html code in html page

Tags: python, html, django, import

i am working on a site which has a sql query and want to make the table thats returns from the select query to be post as html, i have generated the html code that makes the result as a table but i cannot find how i can import in html page

```
import sqlite3
import time

def getQuery(url,email):
    template="""
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Points</th>
  </tr>
"""   
conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
c = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM signups_emails WHERE email LIKE '%walla%'"
try:
    c.execute(sql)
    results = c.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print (row)
        id = row[0]
        email = row[1]
        base = row[2]
        time1 = row[3]
        time2 = row[4]

        lin="""<tr>
    <td>"""+email+"""</td>
    <td>"""+base+"""</td>
  </tr>
  """
        template+=lin
except:
    print "Error: unable to fecth data"
template+="""
</table>
"""
conn.close()
return template
```

at the end i get this code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Site</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>deal@wallashops.co.il</td>
    <td>http://www.wallashops.co.il/</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how can i import it in other html page using render_to_response or any other way ??

Comment: Why are you a) doing manual SQL queries instead of using the orm and b) building up HTML in python rather than using a template?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted code that actually generates the output that you show. Apart from that you need to create a django template that generates your desired HTML.

I suggest that you try reading the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en) - the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/) looks like it might be useful to you. Then look at the [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language).